# UITableViews and UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but if anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. I am creating a app in xcode. I currently have two buttons that segue to different view controllers both view are controlled by the same class. There are separate views defined in the class. I also have two arrays one for each view which is populated with the information I want to show in the view. here is the code from the viewcontrollers .m file. If i remove the breakpoint that appears both buttons function however the second button shows the information from the wrong array but goes to the correct view controller. I am completely stumped.

```
#import "techTwoViewController.h"
#import "maintInstrctViewController.h"
#import "showTechTipsViewController.h"
@interface techTwoViewController ()

@end

@implementation techTwoViewController
{
    NSArray *maintInstrct;
    NSArray *techTips;
}
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize techTableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    maintInstrct = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil];

    techTips = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Three", @"Four", nil];    
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSInteger)techTableView:(UITableView *)techTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [techTips count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)techTableView:(UITableView *)techTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTechTableIdentifier = @"TechTipsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [techTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTechTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTechTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [techTips objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [maintInstrct count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MaintInstrctCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [maintInstrct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMaintKitInstrct"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        maintInstrctViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.maintKitName = [maintInstrct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showTechTips"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.techTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        showTechTipsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.techTipName = [techTips objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: A style note: in Objective-C, properties, methods and variables begin with a lowercase but class names begin with upper case.

Comment: Also, the title of this question is confusing. When you say button, that suggests UIButtons which are not relevant to this question. What you are dealing with is UITableViews and UITableViewCells. Please revise the title of this question.

Comment: This is a classic example of bad OO design patterns. Migrate your table views into their own classes so you don't suffer the issues that @geraldWilliam is highlighting in his answer. A side note: actually use `UITableViewController`s, and add them as subviews to your main view.

Comment: @jsksma Agreed on UITableViewControllers. I suppose I should have mentioned that, but I did want to convey that really any object that conforms to the appropriate protocol would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see whats going on here. You are assigning this view controller as the data source for both of the `UITableViews` it owns. But when your `techTableView` calls its `dataSource`, it has no way of knowing that you want it to call your custom `dataSource` methods. You need to give your `techTableView` its *own* `dataSource`. A separate class that conforms to UITableViewDataSource protocol and implements the necessary methods.